# How to make a sortable table with arrow icons which doesn't 'jump around' which clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize, list.js

I'm trying to adapt the example at http://listjs.com/examples/table/ to create a sortable table in which the table headers are clickable and sort by the corresponding column. I'd like to use up and down arrow icons to indicating ascending and descending order, respectively.

I've included what I have so far at https://jsfiddle.net/khpeek/3gh0r931/12/. The HTML:

```
<div id="users">
  <table>
    <!-- IMPORTANT, class="list" have to be at tbody -->
    <thead>
      <th class="sort" data-sort="name">
        Name
        <i class="material-icons right"></i>
       </th>
      <th class="sort" data-sort="born">
        Born
        <i class="material-icons right"></i>
      </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="list">
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Jonny Stromberg</td>
        <td class="born">1986</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Jonas Arnklint</td>
        <td class="born">1985</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Martina Elm</td>
        <td class="born">1986</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Gustaf Lindqvist</td>
        <td class="born">1983</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

The SCSS (together with Materialize.css and Material Icons):

```
$th-font-size: 15px;

th {
  font-size: $th-font-size;
  i {
    font-size: $th-font-size;
  }
}

.sort:hover {
  background-color:#f3f3f3;
}

.sort.asc > i.material-icons::after {
  content: "arrow_drop_up";
}
.sort.desc > i.material-icons::after {
  content: "arrow_drop_down";
}
```

The Javascript (besides the external library, `list.min.js`, itself):

```
var options = {
  valueNames: [ 'name', 'born' ]
};

var userList = new List('users', options);
```

There are a couple of issues:

- When I, from a 'fresh' (unsorted) page, click on the 'name' `th`, for example, the divider moves ever so slightly down, despite that I've made the `font-size` equal for both the text and the icon. I would like the divider to remain the in the same place.
- When I switch from sorting on 'name' to sorting on 'born' the width of the columns changes to accommodate the modified Material icon. How can I make the columns have a fixed width?
- Currently, when a column is not being sorted by, it doesn't display any up or down arrows. Instead, I'd like such a column to display *both* up and down arrows on top of each other, like a diamond. So far, I haven't even managed to put them next to each other, though (I was getting weird results with three icons appearing), and I'm wondering whether the `:after` approach in CSS is the best way to do this, or whether I should use jQuery.

Any help on any of these issues is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at  https://www.datatables.net/ ? It does all that

Comment: fixed width  https://jsfiddle.net/3gh0r931/13/   fixed height https://jsfiddle.net/3gh0r931/15/

Comment: In both JSFiddles, the `th` text 'Name' still moves vertically ever so slightly. I also would actually like to leave the height as it is, but only change the positioning of the elements within the `th`.